# Jmeter, execute HTTP request again after some sleep time

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter. Writing script as below:

Thread group1: Token generation

Thread group2: Use token created in Thread group1 and call API.

Need to execute Thread group1 after every 10 mins, so that new token is generated and it is used by Thread group2.

Script structure:
[image: Script structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution worked for me:

In Thread group2 call the API.

Then extract the status code using Regular Expression Extractor.

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

Add if controller.

[image: if controller]

NOTE: The only drawback is that, when a request fails then only new token is generated.

Answer (score 2):

1. In order to implement a 10 minutes "sleep" Add a Flow Control Action sampler (earlier was [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action)) to 1st Thread Group and configure it to `Pause` the thread for `600000` milliseconds - 10 minutes

   [image: JMeter Test Action Flow Control]
2. In order to pass token value from one Thread Group into another - use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in 1st thread group to convert JMeter Variable into a JMeter Property and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd thread group to read the token value.

---

According to JMeter Best Practices you should [always be using the latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible.